# Chart.js & Angular 2 - ng2-charts Custom on Click Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to implement ng2-charts in my Angular 2 project and I was wondering about creating custom onclick events. Meaning, I want to override the current onclick events on the carts to do some custom functions (redirect to a page, have a modal show up, etc).

Is there a simple way to do this? Is it built in at all?

Any insight would be appreciated it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to read **[DOCS](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)**

They have pretty good and understandable explanation of use.

There-are built-in 2 event handlers:

**Events**

`chartClick`: fires when click on a chart has occurred, returns information regarding active points and labels

`chartHover`: fires when mousemove (hover) on a chart has occurred, returns information regarding active points and labels

---

In code it looks like that:

```
 <base-chart class="chart"
            [datasets]="lineChartData"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels"
            [options]="lineChartOptions"
            [colors]="lineChartColours"
            [legend]="lineChartLegend"
            [chartType]="lineChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
  </div>
```

that `chartHovered` and `chartClicked` are your custom functions, which could has another names, and do custom things like showing modal, redirect to url etc.

Comment: yeah I saw that, thanks. What about getting data from what piece is actually clicked though? For instance, if you click on one bar (or piece of the pie) how can you access that data from the $event that ng2 is passing? I can't seem to find it looking through the console of the $event that it passes

Comment: For sure you have different `_index`-es on clicking or hovering random pieces of chart. 
`e.active[0]._index`

Comment: thanks. I can see e.active[0] but I can't find within there where the actual data comes through. meaning, how can i tell from that event which actual button was clicked?

Comment: If a user wants to get the label value, while the label in the x axis is clicked and not the bar on the graph. Then how to achieve it

Comment: I have got the solution for my question. I got the Y axis index, if the click is below zero index of Y axis. Then I will continue my logic. So now with the index of x axis that is clicked I can use this index to determine the Label of x axis.

Comment: ````yIndex = child.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].getValueForPixel(e.event.layerY);
                if (yIndex < 0) {
                    xIndex = child.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].getValueForPixel(e.event.layerX);
                }````

Answer (score 19):

I found this solution at https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/489

```
public chartClicked(e: any): void {
if (e.active.length > 0) {
const chart = e.active[0]._chart;
const activePoints = chart.getElementAtEvent(e.event);
  if ( activePoints.length > 0) {
    // get the internal index of slice in pie chart
    const clickedElementIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
    const label = chart.data.labels[clickedElementIndex];
    // get value by index
    const value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[clickedElementIndex];
    console.log(clickedElementIndex, label, value)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public chartClicked(e: any): void {
     console.log(e);
 }
```

`e.active[0]._model` and `e.active[0]._view` contain information about the part of the chart you clicked (i.e. `label`).

Comment: If a user wants to get the label value, while the label in the x axis is clicked and not the bar on the graph. Then how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer is correct. After much searching for the only solution I found was:

```
public chartClicked(e:any):void {

if(e.active.length > 0){
  var points = [];
  var pointSelected = e.active[0]._chart.tooltip._model.caretY;
  var legends = e.active[0]._chart.legend.legendItems;

  for (var i = 0; i < e.active.length; ++i) {
    points.push(e.active[i]._model.y);
  }

  let position = points.indexOf(pointSelected);
  let label = legends[position].text

  console.log("Point: "+label)
}}
```

Comment: If a user wants to get the label value, while the label in the x axis is clicked and not the bar on the graph. Then how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

After checking multiple places, I got it working like this for click event.

HTML:

```
<div class="chart">
  <canvas
    baseChart
    [data]="pieChartData"
    [type]="pieChartType"
    [options]="pieChartOptions"
    [plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
  >
  </canvas>
</div>
```

TS:

```
public chartHovered(e: any): void {
    if (e.event.type == "click") {
      const clickedIndex = e.active[0]?.index;
      console.log("Clicked index=" + clickedIndex);
    }
}
```

[Ref](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)