# chart.js onClick event function, access angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

How to grab angular `component` on onClick function of a ChartJs function? is there a way? as `this` is the Chart, `self` the window...

[image]

My chart is added like that into the `some.component.ts`

```
 @ViewChild(Chart) mainChart: Chart // declaration on public variables on component.ts

  // construction of chart on API call result
  this.mainChart = new Chart(MeasureUnitMonthlyComponent.CHART_ID, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: aChartLabelsArray,
      datasets: aDatasetsArray
    },
    options: {
      onClick: this.onChartClicked,
      legend: {
        display: true
      },
    ....
```

Comment: That TS doesn't look alike an Angular component; define that chart as `@ViewChild`... then it has a parent component.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thx, updated but still dont know how to grab it. Updated the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If you write, `onClick: () => {}`, `this` will be the component/class when writing an arrow function.

If you write, `onClick: function() {}`, `this` will be the chart object.

If you want access to both the chart object and component/class, I would use the utility of `thisAsThat` linked below and explained as well.

[TypeScript: How to use both fat arrow and this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025342/typescript-how-to-use-both-fat-arrow-and-this)

For `onClick:` you can use the utility of `thisAsThat` that's present in the answer where `this` will be the class/component and `that` will be the chart object.

I would also consider using `ng2-charts` which is a wrapper around `chart.js` where it has a `(chartClicked)` event.

[Chart.js & Angular 2 - ng2-charts Custom on Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378984/chart-js-angular-2-ng2-charts-custom-on-click-event)